# Handle Barcode Scanner Value whenever an event is fired from different Program

Tags: barcode-scanner

There's this already-existed program (App A) on my PC which get inputs through barcode scanning. Now, I am developing a another web application (App B).

What I want to do is to read the data scanned by App A and use that value to store on my App B.

Note: I don't have any access on the database on the App A. So the only thing to do is to get the value scanned from App A from the barcode scanner and use it on my new application. How should I do this?

Comment: Which OS? Which scanner? Is the scanner simulating a keyboard?

Comment: I am running on Windows 7, Yes it is simulating.

Comment: Look up "keylogger".

Comment: Where should I find it?